# how do i create a wcf service so that it accepts a soap request when called

Tags: c#, soap

i have created a wcf service which can be called using soap or REST api but i want to add some extra features to my web service so that it accepts some custom data from xml file as a request and returns the filtered data as a response

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure as the title of the post and the description does not gel well.

If you want to create a WCF contract so that a SOAP call can be made to the service, you can look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412196%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

So, any specific input that you want to send need to be put in the SOAP envelope.

Comment: like if i want to send some parameters using xml and that web service accept those parameters and query the database accordingly and retrieve and give the response accordingly

Comment: Any specific need to send the data in XML? Cant you simply use SOAP client?